# Retrieving Windows device's DPI

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

Is there an API in the UWP to retrieve the device dpi? In Android there is the `getDisplayMetrics().density;` method. Is there an equivalent in UWP?

It looks like I'm looking for `RawDPI` or perhaps `ScaleFactor` that used to be available on the phone.

Comment: I found an excellent set of articles on MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The [DpiScaling](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DpiScaling) UWP sample shows how to do this. Specifically, `RawPixelsPerViewPixel`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.aspx) after a bit of digging:

`Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation`

Lots of good stuff available include raw dpi and scale factor.

Answer (score 2):

in Addition to correct answer. There is even more than that you can get actual screen size using.

```
 DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().DiagonalSizeInInches;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding sample how to get the DisplayInformation in C++/winrt

```
#include "winrt/Windows.Graphics.Display.h"

auto displayInfo = Windows::Graphics::Display::DisplayInformation::GetForCurrentView();
```